# RPi-Cam-Web-Interface does not work properly after installing PiHole

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, web-server

I installed a RPi-Cam-Web-Interface using the default settings on my Pi 3. Everything went great, the Web interface worked. After installing PiHole - again with default settings - my web interface always says LOADING.

I have checked the Trouble Shooting regarding this problem on this [site](http://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface#Trouble_Shooting). But it did not solve my problem. I am new to web-servers, can you help me with my problem?

(My installation of Raspbian is up to date).

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by reinstalling the Rpi-WebCam sw, using a different port nr.